# special characteres in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which I use to add rows to database:

when I try to insert values as

> é
>   í
>   á
>   ã

it appears with wrong format 
appears

> ????

the code:

```
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
  <table width="625" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="69">T&iacute;tulo:</td>
      <td width="546"><input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" size="70" maxlength="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Local:</td>
      <td><input name="local" type="text" id="local" size="70" maxlength="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data:</td>
      <td><input name="data" type="text" id="data" maxlength="20" /> 
        (formato: dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Concluir meu Cadastro!" /> 
        <br />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And there is the code from cadastro.php which

```
// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
$titulo = $_POST ["titulo"];    //atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel  
$local  = $_POST ["local"]; //atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
$data   = $_POST ["data"];  //atribuição do campo "ddd" vindo do formulário para variavel

//Gravando no banco de dados !

//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser", "pass");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("db",$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());



$query = "INSERT INTO `CDEventos` ( `id` , `titulo` , `local` , `data`) 
VALUES (0, '$titulo', '$local', '$data')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo "Evento cadastrado com sucesso!";
?> insert in mysql database
```

my mysqldatabase is using latin_general_ci collation

EDIT: now, the collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: You may be supplying UTF-8 data to your database. Are you sure it's encoded correctly the whole way through? It's ideal to use UTF-8 end-to-end instead of Latin1 which is far more restrictive.

Comment: At least use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aaa']) but I'd suggest you to look for PDO as @tadman suggested!

Comment: @tadman I posted wrong..I`m using utf8_general_ci

Comment: Check http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet there are a few tricks how to handle utf-8 correctly.

Comment: You need to ensure it's UTF-8 the whole way through. You may have it converting somewhere in the middle. What data is in your database?

Comment: Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Things that are wrong with your code: you are using old `mysql_` functions. These are long deprecated, and these days we have github and tools like composer, so we can use tested libraries that other teams of people developed which deal with database access and insert. You are not issuing `set names utf8` while connecting so you don't know how PHP speaks to your MySQL. Also, and this is probably the culprit - you didn't show us the charset of HTML page that's used to display records. Basically, many things are wrong.